# Where does .Net Identity storing my user data

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-identity

I am a newbie to .NET web API and struggling with the identity API of it.
I created a new project with MVC Web API template and Individual account authentication.

I tried running the project and calling the Register API and it gives me error with creating the .mdf file.
Then I changed the connection string to a connection string from my another project where I followed data first approach to create user modals. This connection string points to a SQL server database.
    `<add name="myApp"     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.myAppData.csdl|res://*/Models.myAppData.ssdl|res://*/Models.myAppData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=User\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=myDB;user id=sa;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Now when I call Register API, I get status 200 and if I try to call register API with same username again, it says this users already taken. It doesn't appear in my SQL server db neither there is any .mdf file.

Comment: What is your connection string in `web.config`?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the connection string.

Comment: That looks like a messed up connection string. Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Yes, this is an auto-generated connection string I picked from another project in which I followed data-first approach and the wizard generated this string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is storing in your SQLEXPRESS that is installed on your machine.Did you get it ?

If you want to quickly look at the tables.You can do it directly in VS 2013.

In VS 2013,(Screen shot 1 below)

- Open you solution.
- Go to view and Choose Server explorer. 
  You should be able to see a server explorer on the left side of your screen and there should be an option data connection. Double Click on that to connect and login.

For any reason if that does not work, Follow the same steps but choose SQL server Object Explorer (Screen shot 1 below), Using this you should see all the servers installed on your machine you have find the right one

```
Your Database Name = myDB
 user id=sa
 password=xxx
```

[image: VS2013 Server Explorer]

[image: SQL Server Object Explorer]

If all this does not work, Stop Debugging,Open up your main web.config and backup you connection string and updated below connection string .(This connection string will work for local db version 11 which you should get the latest VS, If not update it with the version of local db you have on your machine.).

Create a folder in the project and rename to App_Data.

Build your application and run it.

Now Stop it and Click on Show all files in Solution Explorer.

You should now see a mydb.mdf file in the App_Data folder in the solution explorer,which is your temporary database. 
Double click and access it.

if you cannot figure this out in App_data folder, then follow the steps of using SQL Server Object explorer.

```html
<add name="myApp"     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.myAppData.csdl|res://*/Models.myAppData.ssdl|res://*/Models.myAppData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDB1.mdf;initial catalog=myDB1;user id=sa;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. The problem with this process is that I am getting access rights issue when VS tries to create the .mdf file in App_Data folder. This is even when I run VS as Administrator

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot?